# how can i include files for all functions in php

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm new in php as you know and i have some problems (like any new starts) and my problem is i cant include file like `config.php` to all functions in the files

i have just 3 files

in `config.php` i just connect to database in mysqli and the variable is `$connect`

in functions.php there is just a simple functions

```
include('config.php');
function rows($table){
    $gettables = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM $table");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($gettables);
    return($numrows);
}
```

in index.php

```
include('functions.php');
echo rows('books');
```

and the problem is i cant get `$connect` variable from `config.php` to work in functions in `functions.php` file.

**EDIT**

when i include `config.php` inside the functions everything will be ok,
like this

```
function rows($table){
include('config.php');
    $gettables = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM $table");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($gettables);
    return($numrows);
}
```

but i don't want to do this because i want to include a `config.php` for all functions i have.

Thanks

Comment: try require_once instead of include

Comment: Either move to classes, pass the variable `connect` to the function instead of including it or make use of the `global` keyword

Comment: @Exprator i tried it, not worked.

Comment: Including files in functions can bring unexpected errors. The inclusion happens at runtime and this means the included file is loaded and parsed every time the function runs. This produces problems if the include file contains things that cannot be declared twice (defines, functions, classes).

Comment: @axiac Thanks dude, i just use global here to connect database, in other time i will not forget your words ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$connect exists in 'config.php'.

In your function(s), declare $connect as 'global' ie: it exists outside the scope of this function.

```
function rows($table){

    global $connect;

    $gettables = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM $table");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($gettables);
    return($numrows);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Two possible ways are avaliable.

1.Passing $connect as a second parameter to the function

```
include('config.php');
function rows($table,$connnect){
    $gettables = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM $table");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($gettables);
    return($numrows);
}
```

2. Declaring $connect as a global variable

   ```
    function rows($table){
           global $connect;
           $gettables = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM $table");
           $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($gettables);
           return($numrows);
       }
   ```

It is recommended to pass $connect as a parameter to the function.Not recommended to use global variable refer here [Are global variables in PHP considered bad practice? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)

Comment: Thanks for the info dude, i will use global because my codes are simple, in other project i will not forget your words :), Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you declare a variable in the global scope, however whatever is available in the global scope is not automatically available in the function scope unless your force it available via `global $connect` which has its own caveats.

Some alternatives to `global` would be.

1) Use a singleton class:

```
<?php
//File connect.php
class Connection {
    private static $connection = null;
    public static get() {
          if (self::$connection == null) { self::$connection = mysqli_connect(...); }
          return self::$connection;
    }
}
```

And use it as

```
include_once('connect.php');
function rows($table){
    $gettables = mysqli_query(Connection::get(),"SELECT * FROM $table");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($gettables);
    return($numrows);
}
```

2) Constants (Not the best idea):

```
 <?php 
 //File config.php
 define('CONNECTION',mysqli_connect(...));
```

Use as:

```
include_once('config.php');
function rows($table){
    $gettables = mysqli_query(CONNECTION,"SELECT * FROM $table");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($gettables);
    return($numrows);
}
```

3) Pass it as a parameter to the function (config.php is as you have it now):

```
function rows($connection, $table){
    $gettables = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM $table");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($gettables);
    return($numrows);
}
```

Use as:

```
include('config.php');
include_once('functions.php');
echo rows($connection, 'books');
```

4) Have the file work like a variable declaration

```
<?php
//config.php 
return mysqli_connect(...);
```

Use as:

```
function rows($table){
     $connect = include('config.php');
     $gettables = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM $table");
     $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($gettables);
     return($numrows);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initiate a new object config inside your function and use the constructer to conect to database like this

```
$c=new config();
$con=$c->connect();
$req="SELECT * FROM table";
$conn=$con->query($req);
```

this works if you have done a class config in config.php